# TypeError while converting pandas column to int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Working with pandas data frame, where one of the columns, say col1 has floating point values, I am trying to divide each of these values with a pre defined constant, say A, and then save the results as integer values.

```
A = 0.5
```

Following is the data in **col1**

```
df["col1"]

0     0.800000
1     0.883333
2     0.883333
3     1.000000
4     1.000000
5     1.300000
6     1.300000
7     1.500000
8     1.500000
9     2.000000
10    2.000000
11    2.500000
12    2.500000
```

After applying

```
df["new_col"] = (df["col1"] / A)
```

It gives

```
0     1.600000
1     1.766667
2     1.766667
3     2.000000
4     2.000000
5     2.600000
6     2.600000
7     3.000000
8     3.000000
9     4.000000
10    4.000000
11    5.000000
12    5.000000
```

which is fine, but as soon as I add **.astype(int)** to the above code, it can be observed at **index 9 and 10** the values are **3** and **3** whereas it should be 4 and 4 respectively.

```
df["new_col"] = (df["col1"] / A).astype(int)
df["new_col"]

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     3
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    5
12    5
```

The other ways I am trying to obtain the result are

```
 df["new_col"] = math.floor(df["col1"] / A )
```

and

```
df["new_col"] = int( df["col1"] / A)
```

Both of which gives me TypeError saying:

TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float'  **and** 
 TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'   respectively.

Please let me know how should I resolve the above issues.

Comment: Wierd. I am getting 4,4 in both the locations.

Comment: I guess, I should restart my system then and try again, otherwise I've tried the code 10 times and it shows me 3 and 3.

Comment: That's probably a floating point issue. If it's represented as 3.99999 astype will round it down to 3. Try `round(0)` maybe?

Comment: @ayhan I did what u suggested, using .round(0) , but the problem is it works as a ceiling function, it makes values like 2.6,  2.87  to 3, whereas I want them to be 2. What else can I try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have rounding issue. What you see as `4.000000` is probably `3.9999999999` internally, so you get this result. ( try `df.col1-2` to check it.)

You can try  `(df.round(6)/.5).astype(int)` to work on the digits you see, but it is a workaround.

Comment: What if all the values in the above column are negative, so in case of -3.999999, it will be rounded to -4 ?

Comment: It's dangerous to continue this way. I think  if your computations lead to 3.999 when 4 is the good result, you must refactor this part.

Comment: I am still struggling with this, now one of the values in column is -7.680000 and I am dividing it with 0.04000 , it should be -192, but I get -191 which affects my overall result. Please suggest the refactoring part yo mentioned. I am sorry, haven't encountered this type of problem before, so just running out of solutions. I have a column which has only negative floating point numbers which I will be dividing with another **positive** floating point no, and then keeping only the integer part of the result (like floor and **not** ceiling).